# How to install QJson in Qt creator (Qt 4.8.6)

Tags: c++, json, linux, qt, qt4

I want to use QJson in Qt creator.  I'm using Qt 4.8.6 so there is no Json lib in the QtCore like in Qt5.

I have been to the sourceforge site: http://qjson.sourceforge.net/build/ and it says that I should install qjson using package manage tools. So I installed *libqjson0, libqjson-dev, libqjson-dbg and libqjson0-dbg* package using apt-get install.

Than I created a new project and copy the official site's example to it. I alse modified my .pro file, I added an external library (*libqjson.so*) so Qt creator automatically added the following code to the .pro file:

`win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/release/ -lqjson
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/ -lqjson
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lqjson
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

The *libqjson.so* file is in the *x86_64-linux-gnu* path.
I also added a line including the parse.h file and other files with it:
`INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../usr/include/qjson`

After that, I can include , but I can't use the function like *toMap(), toString()* in my code...

I think there must be something wrong in my install procedure.  Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QJson::Parser parser;
    bool ok;

    QString json;
    json = "{\"encoding\" : \"UTF-8\",\"plug-ins\": [\"python\",\"c++\", \"ruby\"],\"indent\":{\"length\": 3,\"use_space\":true}}";

    QVariantMap result = parser.parse(json, &ok).toMap();
    if (!ok) {
      qFatal("An error occurred during parsing");
      exit (1);
    }

    qDebug() << "encoding:" << result["encoding"].toString();
    qDebug() << "plugins:";

    foreach (QVariant plugin, result["plug-ins"].toList()) {
      qDebug() << "\t-" << plugin.toString();
    }

    QVariantMap nestedMap = result["indent"].toMap();
    qDebug() << "length:" << nestedMap["length"].toInt();
    qDebug() << "use_space:" << nestedMap["use_space"].toBool();
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QJsons w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

And this is my error information:

08:40:53: Running steps for project QJson...
08:40:53: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
08:40:53: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/bin/qmake -spec /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/mkspecs/linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug -o Makefile ../QJson/QJson.pro
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../QJson -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtGui -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include -I/home/cecaadmin/GRT/QtProjects/TranferFileDemo/QJson/../../../usr/include/qjson -I/usr/include/qjson -I. -I../QJson -I. -o main.o ../QJson/main.cpp

../QJson/main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':

../QJson/main.cpp:13:48: error: no matching function for call to

'QJson::Parser::parse(QString&, bool*)'
     QVariantMap result = parser.parse(json, &ok).toMap();
                                                ^
../QJson/main.cpp:13:48: note: candidates are:
In file included from ../QJson/main.cpp:4:0:
/usr/include/qjson/parser.h:51:16: note: QVariant QJson::Parser::parse(QIODevice*, bool*)
       QVariant parse(QIODevice* io, bool* ok = 0);
                ^
/usr/include/qjson/parser.h:51:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'QString' to 'QIODevice*'
/usr/include/qjson/parser.h:61:16: note: QVariant QJson::Parser::parse(const QByteArray&, bool*)
       QVariant parse(const QByteArray& jsonData, bool* ok = 0);
                ^
/usr/include/qjson/parser.h:61:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'QString' to 'const QByteArray&'
../QJson/main.cpp:19:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QDebug'
     qDebug() << "encoding:" << result["encoding"].toString();
            ^
In file included from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore/qnamespace.h:45:0,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:45,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtGui/qwindowdefs.h:45,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtGui/qwidget.h:46,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtGui/QWidget:1,
                 from ../QJson/qjsons.h:4,
                 from ../QJson/main.cpp:1:

/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:1793:7: error: forward declaration of 'class QDebug'
 class QDebug;
       ^

../QJson/main.cpp:20:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QDebug'
     qDebug() << "plugins:";
            ^
In file included from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore/qnamespace.h:45:0,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:45,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtGui/qwindowdefs.h:45,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtGui/qwidget.h:46,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtGui/QWidget:1,
                 from ../QJson/qjsons.h:4,
                 from ../QJson/main.cpp:1:

/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:1793:7: error: forward declaration of 'class QDebug'
 class QDebug;
       ^

../QJson/main.cpp:23:14: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QDebug'
       qDebug() << "\t-" << plugin.toString();
              ^
In file included from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore/qnamespace.h:45:0,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:45,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtGui/qwindowdefs.h:45,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtGui/qwidget.h:46,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtGui/QWidget:1,
                 from ../QJson/qjsons.h:4,
                 from ../QJson/main.cpp:1:

/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:1793:7: error: forward declaration of 'class QDebug'
 class QDebug;
       ^

../QJson/main.cpp:27:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QDebug'
     qDebug() << "length:" << nestedMap["length"].toInt();
            ^
In file included from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore/qnamespace.h:45:0,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:45,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtGui/qwindowdefs.h:45,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtGui/qwidget.h:46,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtGui/QWidget:1,
                 from ../QJson/qjsons.h:4,
                 from ../QJson/main.cpp:1:

/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:1793:7: error: forward declaration of 'class QDebug'
 class QDebug;
       ^

../QJson/main.cpp:28:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QDebug'
     qDebug() << "use_space:" << nestedMap["use_space"].toBool();
            ^
In file included from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore/qnamespace.h:45:0,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:45,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtGui/qwindowdefs.h:45,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtGui/qwidget.h:46,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtGui/QWidget:1,
                 from ../QJson/qjsons.h:4,
                 from ../QJson/main.cpp:1:

/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:1793:7: error: forward declaration of 'class QDebug'
 class QDebug;
       ^
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore/qglobal.h: At global scope:
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:1796:29: warning: inline function 'QDebug qDebug()' used but never defined [enabled by default]
 Q_CORE_EXPORT_INLINE QDebug qDebug();
                             ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
08:40:54: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project QJson (kit: Desktop)
When executing step 'Make'

Comment: Show us the code where the calls are failing and the compiler error messages that are given.

Comment: I think you also need at least
QT += Debug in your .pro file.  I see it complaining about QDebug.

Comment: in Qt5 QJson exists out of box..

Comment: The errors pertain to qdebug, not qjson.